# AHK ControlSend {s Down} not working in game

Tags: autohotkey

Has anyone ever had any luck with the following scenario

I am writing code for Mortal Online, it requires a key to be pressed down when the game is not focused. All other commands work perfectly in this code except the "controlSend, ,{s Down}, ahk_id %id%" & "controlSend, ,{s Up}, ahk_id %id%" respectively.

```
training() {
    ;set variabls to global
    global

    id := getMortalID()

    while(Continue()) { 
        if(toolTipToggle) {
            ToolTip, Auto Train, 15, 85         
        }

        ;Take out weapon and run forward
        controlSend, ,%sheath%, ahk_id %id%     
        sleep 2000              
        controlSend, ,%autorun%, ahk_id %id%            
        loop 100 {
            if(!Continue()) {                   
                    controlSend, ,%autorun%, ahk_id %id%
                    sleep 50
                    controlSend, ,%sheath%, ahk_id %id%
                    Return
            }
            controlSend, ,{LShift}, ahk_id %id%
            sleep 100
        }

        ;stop running forward and jump backward
        Sleep 50
        controlSend, ,%autorun%, ahk_id %id%
        Sleep 50        
        loop 10 {               
            if(!Continue()) {       
                ControlSend, ,%sheath%, ahk_id %id%
                Return
            }       

            controlSend, ,{s Down}, ahk_id %id%
            sleep 10000
            controlSend, ,{s Up}, ahk_id %id%

        }

        ;stop jumping back and sheath weapon then sleep for 15s
        Sleep 50
        controlSend, ,%sheath%, ahk_id %id%
        sleep 2000      
        if(!Continue()) 
                Return                      
        controlSend, ,%sleeping%, ahk_id %id%
        Sleep 15000
    }   ; repeat

    AnyScreen = 0
}
```

Anyone have any solution to this? I have tried keydelays, have #InstallKeybdHook set.

Thank you for you consideration in advance.

Comment: Have you tried "[Sendmode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SendMode.htm),Play" ?

Comment: Yup no luck with that.

Comment: What is the code for `getMortalID()` ?

Comment: It is a function to find the AHK_ID of a game client. Works well.